# ¿Por qué el array cambia de valor y no sucede lo mismo con la variable int?

Tags: c#, array, variables

Quiero saber porque el array cambia de valor y no sucede lo mismo con la variable int.

Ejemplo:

```
   public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Otraclase objeto1 = new Otraclase();
        int[] arr = new int[] { 10 };
        int variable = 10;

        objeto1.Metodo(arr,variable);

        Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(variable);

    }
}

class Otraclase
{
   public void Metodo(int[]arra, int vari)
    {
        arra[0] = 20;
        vari = 20;
```

Resultado: 
Array: 20
Variable int: 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Porque el array cambia de valor y no sucede lo mismo con la variable int?

Al invocarse este método:

```cs
objeto1.Metodo(arr,variable);
```

Suceden dos cosas:

- Al primer parámetro se le está pasando la dirección de memoria al que apunte la variable `arr`. Sin embargo, aquí se **pasó por valor**, es decir, lo que tendrá el parámetro es una copia del contenido de `arr`. Por esa razón, durante la ejecución del método, no podemos modificar el contenido de la variable `arr`, pero si podemos alterar el contenido del objeto original (por esa razón puedes hacer esto: `arra[0] = 20`) al que apuntaba `arr` y esto se debe, porque justamente esa **copia** es la **dirección base** de un objeto.
- El segundo parámetro también se pasa por valor, debido a que, el parámetro tendrá una copia del contenido de la variable. Así que al asignar un `20` al parámetro, nunca alterará el contenido de la variable original.

Para pasar por referencia, debemos usar el operador `ref`.

**Ejemplo:**

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Otraclase objeto1 = new Otraclase();
        int[] arr = new int[] { 10 };
        int variable = 10;

        objeto1.Metodo(ref arr, ref variable);

        Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(variable);
        //Resultado por pantalla: 11 y 20.
    }
}

class Otraclase
{
    public void Metodo(ref int[]arra, ref int vari)
    {
        arra = new int[]{11};
        vari = 20;
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarse el método, se le está pasando al parámetro `arra` la dirección de memoria donde esté alojado la variable `arr`, por lo tanto, durante la ejecución del método, podemos alterar el contenido de la variable original y también el contenido al que apunte `arr`. El argumento que se le pasa al parámetro `vari` también se pasa por referencia. Esta es la razón del porque se puede alterar las variables `arr` y `variable`.

Comment: Me parece que en mi ejemplo en ningun momento se esta haciendo un paso por referencia, porque si aplicamos el mismo ejemplo en java nos daria el mismo resultado y en java no se puede pasar un parametro a un metodo por referencia.

Comment: Se estaria pasando un valor como argumento, una copia de una variable que contiene una referencia a la direccion de un objeto.

Comment: @user148581 Tienes toda la razón. No suelo usar estos conceptos en la práctica y le pido disculpa si lo hice confundir. Suelo enfocarme en la mayoría de las veces, en como funciona internamente (si lo analizas en como lo interpreta el compilador, estos conceptos de pase por referencia y de valor quedan irrelevantes). Edité toda la respuesta que había hecho anteriormente. Espero te sirva! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Porque no estas modificando los valores que tu crees, al llamar la clase "Metodo" los cambios se quedan dentro de esta, no los has aplicado en tu clase principal, lo que deberías hacer es que ese metodo te retorne algo y entonces asignarselo a la variable que quieres modificar, ejemplo:

```
arr[0] = objeto1.modificar(20);
variable = objeto1.modificar(20);
```